# async void event handlers - clarification?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I'm trying to understand the reason *why* is it bad to do: *(notice, context here is asp.net, regardless the plain reason that `async void` can't be tracked)*

```
 public async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
}
```

Well , after investigating a bit I saw few *different* reasons :

- Damian Edwards Says [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx)  that:

  > Async void event handlers in web forms **are only supported on certain
  >   events**, as you've found, but are really only intended for simplistic
  >   tasks. We recommend using PageAsyncTask for any async work of any real
  >   complexity.
- Levi  Says [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx)  that:

  > Async events in web applications are inherently strange beasts. Async
  >   void is meant for a fire and forget programming model. This works in
  >   Windows UI applications since the application sticks around until the
  >   OS kills it, so whenever the async callback runs there is guaranteed
  >   to be a UI thread that it can interact with. In web applications, this
  >   model falls apart since requests are by definition transient. **If the
  >   async callback happens to run after the request has finished, there is
  >   no guarantee that the data structures the callback needs to interact
  >   with are still in a good state**. Thus why fire and forget (and async
  >   void) is inherently a bad idea in web applications.
  >
  > That said, we do crazy gymnastics to try to make very simple things
  >   like Page_Load work, but the code to support this is extremely
  >   complicated and not well-tested for anything beyond basic scenarios.
  >   So if you need reliability I’d stick with RegisterAsyncTask.
- [This site](http://codewala.net/tag/async/) says:

  > As we know
  >   our page life cycle has a set of events that gets fired in a
  >   predefined order **and next event will be fired only when the last event
  >   completes.** So if we use the above way of async Page_Load, this event
  >   will be fired during page life cycle event once it reaches to async,
  >   current thread gets free and a another thread got assigned to complete
  >   the task asynchronously, **but the ASP.NET cannot execute the next event
  >   in life cycle because Page_Load has not been completed yet**. And
  >   underlying synchronization context waits till the asynchronous
  >   activity completes. Then only the next event of page lifecycle will be
  >   fired which makes the whole process in synchronous mode only.
- [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) site says

  > **when the return type is void, the
  >   caller might assume the method is complete by the time it returns**.
  >   This problem can crop up in many unexpected ways. It’s usually wrong
  >   to provide an async implementation (or override) of a void-returning
  >   method on an interface (or base class). **Some events also assume that
  >   their handlers are complete when they return**.

I see here very **different**  (non-overlapping) reasons.

**Question :**

**What** is the glory/true reason for which we shouldn't write `public async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

---

nb, I also don't know why it is a problem since 4.5 does use the [UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx) which its  [aim is to support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9662023/859154):

`protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){...}`

Comment: Notice how all of the ASP related links say that it's okay, and all of the non-ASP related links say that you should be very careful about how you use `async void`.  That should tell you something, that ASP is special.  And if you read through some of your own links, they even explain *why* ASP is special, and how it went about allowing `async void` methods to work as you would want them to; of course, that's only for the simple cases; it also explains when it won't work, and what to do then.

Comment: @Servy Levi and Damian are in the asp.net development....so i found it hard not to believe them....but on the other hand....the other reasons seems legit also....so...:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The articles you link to make the reasons pretty clear. Don't use it because it isn't reliable beyond the most basic of scenarios. There is only so much async tracking trickery we can pull in the synchronization context on async void methods. We did work to make those basic scenarios work, but our general guidance is to avoid using them and instead explicitly register async work.

Comment: Hello Damian, in an effort to "avoid async void" I used the `RegisterAsyncTask` during the Page_Load eventhandler, but I was unable to get any data to bind to the Telerik RadGrid. The methods are all called and return data, but the data bind fails.
Could you help me understand what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**I haven't verified this**, but I think it's OK to use `async void Page_Load(...)` in ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms, for as long as the page has `<%@ Page Async="true" ... %>` declaration.

I think so based on the [implementation of `AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/AspNetSynchronizationContext.cs#ce8ef76064b0a11e), which is called when any `async void` method is invoked on a thread with `AspNetSynchronizationContext`. Here's a relevant comment:

```
 // If the caller tries to kick off an asynchronous operation while we are not
 // processing an async module, handler, or Page, we should prohibit the operation.
```

Apparently, pages with `Async="true"` do not violate this requirement, and the HTTP request processing isn't going to be completed until all pending operations have completed, including `async void` ones.